# wp_login_form redirect problem

Tags: redirect, page-template, wp-login-form

I have added a login form to a page template using wp_login_form(). This page template is used for a welcome/login page for an online seminar. When the user logs in I want them to be redirected to the online seminar page.
Here is the code I used:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {               
            echo '<div class="logout"> <p>Hello!<div class="logout_user"> You are logged in and can proceed to the <a href="http://example.com/seminar">Online Seminar</a>.</div></p><br /><p><a id="wp-submit" class="logout" href="', wp_logout_url(), '" title="Logout">Logout</a></p></div>';
        } else { 
          wp_login_form($args);

                  $args = array(
                            'echo'           => true,
                            'redirect'       => site_url('/seminar'),
                            'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log in' ),
                            'form_id'        => 'seminar-login',
                            'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
                            'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
                            'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
                            'id_username'    => 'user_login',
                            'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
                            'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
                            'remember'       => true,
                            'value_username' => NULL,
                            'value_remember' => true
                            ); 
        }
```

When I set it up yesterday it seemed to be redirecting just fine, but today it just stays on the welcome/login page. I read that this is the default action, so it seems to be ignoring the redirect. I tried using an absolute url:

`'redirect'       => 'http://example.com/seminar',`

But, that didn't work either.

I've tried to think what might be affecting this (ie. plugin conflicts) and two things might be relevant. I use AIOWPSecurity to rename the login page and access to the seminar itself is controlled by the Groups plugin. But, that doesn't explain why it was working when I set it up yesterday, but not working now.

Does anyone have any ideas why the redirect doesn't work?

Thank You!

Comment: Define the $args array BEFORE the call to wp_login_form().

Comment: What @shanebp said and you were already using an absolute URL as the redirect value. `site_url( '/seminar/ ' )` will produce an absolute URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains a mistake in passing arguments to the `wp_login_form()` function. If you define the arguments after function then the function will be called with the default values, so your arguments will not have any effect. The correct code is below:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {               
    echo '<div class="logout"> <p>Hello!<div class="logout_user"> You are logged in and can proceed to the <a href="http://example.com/seminar">Online Seminar</a>.</div></p><br /><p><a id="wp-submit" class="logout" href="', wp_logout_url(), '" title="Logout">Logout</a></p></div>';
} else { 
    $args = array(
        'echo'           => true,
        'redirect'       => 'http://example.com/seminar',
        'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log in' ),
        'form_id'        => 'seminar-login',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'id_username'    => 'user_login',
        'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
        'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
        'remember'       => true,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => true
    );
    wp_login_form($args); 
}
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to what your code does and how it works. And stop using other accounts to vote your answers up.

Comment: So simple. I can't believe I spent so long looking for the answer. Thank you!